# Simple question: filter dictionary of a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

imagine I have a list

`List<String> B`

and a dictionary

`Dictionary<String, int> A`

How can I return a Dictionary<**String, int**> that filtered from A with the keys in B by using Linq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy, using `Where` to filter the key/value pairs, and then [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) to build a new dictionary.

```
var c = A.Where(pair => B.Contains(pair.Key))
         .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

If you have a lot of entries, you may want to create a `HashSet<string>` first:

```
var strings = new HashSet<string>(B);
var c = A.Where(pair => strings.Contains(pair.Key))
         .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

That will make it faster to test each key.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head, because I'm on the wrong computer and cannot test. But you should get the idea:

```
A.Where(val => B.Contains(val.Key)).ToDictionary(val => val.Key, val => val.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary is big, you might want to enumerate the B instead of A.

```
var filtered = B
        .Where(key => A.ContainsKey(key))
        .ToDictionary(key => key, key => A[key]);
```